# how to check email exist in rails, devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, jquery-validate

I am a beginner at Ruby.

I have created my website using Rails, and am using the Devise gem to create users.
In sign_up. **users/registrations/new.html.erb** I have:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :"Email address  *" %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control" , placeholder: "Enter your email", name: "email" %>
</div>
```

And I am using a jQuery validation plugin on my validation form, adding a new rule:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkAlreadyEmail", function( value, element ) {
  var unavailable = true;
  $.ajax({
    url : '/users/check_already_email',
    type : "POST",
    async: false,
    data : 'email =' + value,
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(data) {
      if(data.available == true){
        unavailable = false;
      }
    }
  });
  return unavailable;
}, "This email is already taken");

$("#new_user").validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      checkAlreadyEmail: true,
      },}
messages: {
    email: {
      required: "Please enter your email",
      email: "Please enter valid email address",
      checkAlreadyEmail: "This email is already taken",
    },},})
```

In users/registrations_controller.rb I have

```
def check_already_email
    @email = users.search(params[:email])
  end
```

What is next ? I am sorry, this is the first time I am asking a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: This is q pretty broad question.  Do you have anything you really want to know?

Comment: i'm sorry , i only want check email exist in rails, and display that by messages in validate . Thank Rohit Gupta :)

Comment: Why do you want to use JQuery to do your validation? You can easily add validation to your User model with `validates :email, unique: true `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How the process works is,

1 - User fill the form

2 - User click `submit` button

3 - `JQuery validator` will validate the form depending on your rules defined, and if everything if ok submit the form (which will create a user in the DB)

as per your code, you should add a route in `config/routes.rb` to handle the request `check_already_email`. something like..

```
#config/routes.rb
get "registrations/check_already_email" =>"registrations#check_email", as: :check_email
```

Following is [almost the same thing which you try to do](https://bestror.wordpress.com/2013/06/29/validation-form-in-ruby-on-rails-with-jquery-validate/), have a look